# Searching xml file in java to see if an element exists not working?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a directory with 3 files in it. This is supposed to loop through the files and process each xml file. It looks for the element "Booking" or "BookingOutputPlan" depending on which element it has in it, it is processed a different way.

```
NodeList l = null;
NodeList n = null;
int counter = 0;
for (counter = 0; counter < files.size(); counter++) {
  Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(files.get(counter));
  l = d.getElementsByTagName("Booking");
  n = d.getElementsByTagName("BookTripPlanOutput");
}

for (int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); ++i) {
  GMFiles.add(files.get(i));
  processGMXml(GMFiles, prop, log);
}
for (int a = 0; a < n.getLength(); ++a) {
  ACFiles.add(files.get(a));
  processACXml(ACFiles, prop, log);
}
}
```

I get the arraylist for the files by doing this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;
    in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();

    // location of directory
    File directory = new File(prop.getProperty("directory"));

    // creates array list of files
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    // gets all the files in that directory and puts into array
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : listFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                files.add(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            }

        }// end of for-loop listFiles
```

Comment: Explian your question more please. Is there any exception?

Comment: It only processes the first file then stops. It doesn't account for the other 2 files in the directory. Sorry I am new to parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are overwriting the value of l and n since the the first for loop keeps on running till the last file. Only thenit will come out of the loop and execute the last 2 loops. The last two loops which calls the parsing method should be inside your first for loop.

```
NodeList l = null;
NodeList n = null;
int counter = 0;
for (counter = 0; counter < files.size(); counter++) {
     Document d   =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(files.get(counter));
         l = d.getElementsByTagName("Booking");
         n = d.getElementsByTagName("BookTripPlanOutput");
        for (int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); ++i) {
                GMFiles.add(files.get(i));
                processGMXml(GMFiles, prop, log);

        }
        for (int a = 0; a < n.getLength(); ++a) {
                ACFiles.add(files.get(a));
                processACXml(ACFiles, prop, log);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why would that make it use the first file only ? Not the last file ?

Comment: I tried this but it still only uses the first file and just processes it 3 times.

Comment: Ya it should be using just the last file. Are you sure its the first file and that there is no exception thrown in your calls to the parse method

Comment: Can you post your entire code here? I thats the case, your file ArrayList has the same file name three times. Show me how you get this array list

Comment: Is there a different way to approach this instead of using for-loops ?

Comment: Debug your code and see if directory and listFiles have all three filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is a little strange but I think the way it's written, NodeLists l and n will always only contain the list of nodes in the last file because your initial for-loop finishes completely before parsing the NodeLists.

You need to put your two parsing for-loops need to be inside the initial for-loop. Either that, or append to your node lists on each file iteration instead of assign.